# How to change link color (Struts2 jquery link) on click?

Tags: java, jquery, html, struts2, struts2-jquery

I am using struts2-jquery-plugin-3.2.1 in my application.And i am using  links ,now i want to change the color of selected link.Please share your ideas. Thank you in advance.

```
<s:url id="ajax" action="OpenCustomAddedRoutines1" escapeAmp="false">
           <s:param name="rid" value="routineId"></s:param>
           <s:param name="DayCount" value="dayCount"></s:param>
</s:url>
<sj:a href="%{ajax}" button="true" targets="buttonDiv"></sj:a>
```

Comment: thanks for your comment,but i am using  struts2-jquery-plugin-3.2.1 so how to put css and jquery in that i am new to struts 2 jquery.

Comment: can't you use cssClass property of the tag to apply the desired css?

Comment: The thing you seem to be missing is that all that JS and Java translates to **HTML** by the time it is rendered by a browser.  Understand how to do this in a page using plain HTML (without any JS) and you can likely do it almost exactly the same in your struts app.

Comment: @Umesh awasthi- yes you are right but i am not able to get where to change .

Comment: what color change you want? do you want on-hover changes or the color change after user clicked on the link

Comment: color change after user clicked on the link.....

Comment: Use the `:visited` selector. For instance: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp